# PHP - output video file without playing when clicking php script

Tags: php, security, video-streaming, html5-video

**Info:**

I have a web page along the lines of:

`<video width="400" controls>
   <source src="getvideo.php" type="video/mp4">
  </video>`

In my `getvideo.php` file, I have a script (similar solution to this: http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/) which will load a video from a secure, private location outside the web root (e.g home/sites/test/protected/video.mp4) - [this is necessary as I don't want anyone to be able to access or view the video file directly] - and create a buffer to stream the video. This is all fine and working as expected.

**The problem:**

If you directly enter the URL (www.exampledomain.com/getvideo.php) of the PHP file, it will automatically load the video on the screen and you will be able to play it. This is not desired functionality. Instead, I want the video to be secured from direct access. This can be achieved for image files by using the readfile($imagePath) but does not work for video files. (in the case of images, if you try to access the PHP file directly, it will just output meaningless information about the image) - Is it possible to achieve something like this with video output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement makes me think of a CSRF attack except that your "attacks" may be coming from authenticated users and not antagonistic sites. So I guess you could use something like the [synchronizer token pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) that one uses to protect against CSRF attacks. You would generate a new random token and store it somewhere that getvideo.php could access for validation. Then, getvideo.php will only return the video if it is called with a valid token.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as its a good solution to the problem